# Attributes not included to form becomes null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Good time of the day

I have some problems in Spring boot

Situation: I am doing Update operation. My controller receiving the instance of object via service and adding to model.

In form, I want to change some attributes of object, and showing attributes via input tag, like

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{name}" >
```

Problem

The attributes not added to form becomes null after submitting the form. While all attributes included on form showing the new values or old ones after submitting.

My Controller

```
@GetMapping("/recipe/{recipeId}/ingredient/{id}/edit")
public String editRecipeIngredient(@PathVariable String recipeId, @PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    IngredientCommand command = ingredientService.findByRecipeIdAndIngredientId(Long.valueOf(recipeId), Long.valueOf(id)); // instance of class
    model.addAttribute("ingredient", command);
    log.info("The recipe id before POST === " + command.getRecipeID());
    model.addAttribute("uoms", unitOfMeasureService.findAllUoms());
    return "recipe/ingredient/ingredientform";
}

@PostMapping
@RequestMapping("/recipe/{recipeId}/ingredient")
public String updateIngredient(@ModelAttribute IngredientCommand command) {
    log.info("The recipe id after POST === " + command.getRecipeID());
    log.info("Amount " + command.getAmount());
    IngredientCommand savedIngredient = ingredientService.saveIngredientCommand(command);
    return "redirect:/ingredi";
}
```

My form

```
<form class="form" th:object="${ingredient}" th:action="'/recipe/'+${ingredient.id}+'/ingredient'" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" th:field="*{recipeID}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Description
            <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" class="form-control">
        </label>
        <label> Amount
            <input type="number" th:field="*{amount}" class="form-control">
        </label>
        <label>Unif of Measure
            <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
                <option th:each="uom:${uoms}"
                        th:value="${uom.id}"
                        th:text="${uom.description}"
                        th:selected="${uom.id.equals(ingredient.uom.id)}">
                    Option
                </option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Result[image]

Is it normal behavior? Or maybe I can to not specify some attributes in form and save their values?

Comment: You have nicely formed your question and included lot's of useful data, but could you please add your code preformatted like <pre><code>your_code</code></pre> instead of embedding images of it!
Thx

Comment: Now I replaced images with code blocks @Csisanyi

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the attribute name in the POST param?
Could you try it like this

```
public String updateIngredient(@ModelAttribute("ingredient") IngredientCommand command)
```

Comment: It's not worked. I think attribute name is not required here.

Comment: what if you pass in the modal to your POST and get IngredientCommand from it inside your method?